# How to fix the connection error in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have created a new project in django. when I run **python manage.py runserver**, I am getting the msg in command prompt like below.

```
 /var/www/samplepro/myapp$ python manage.py runserver
 Performing system checks...

 System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
 March 26, 2015 - 10:52:31
 Django version 1.7.7, using settings 'myapp.settings'
 Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
 Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

when I test in browser, I am getting the page can't be displayed error. Can anyone help me to do get the django page.

Comment: Just to check - what link are you going to in your browser?

Comment: I jus entered http://127.0.0.1:8000 in my browser

Comment: Okay... and do any connection attempts appear in the log? If not... that's one problem, if so - and you get an error of some sort - that's another...

Comment: when I check fix connection problems in  browser, it showing the issues like "The remote device or resource won't accept the connection"

Comment: There might be some error in the network script of your os or the /etc/hosts file

Comment: what I have to change in the hosts file.

Comment: You might also want to check your firewall -- your OS might be blocking connection requests by default. How to do this will depend on what kind of machine you're using. On Linux, read about iptables(1). On OS X, look at System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall.

Comment: am using windows 8.. I checked it in explorer

Comment: and you are running django on the same machine?

Comment: no am running django with Ubuntu server using putty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated that you are running the server on Ubuntu while you are trying to connect it from another PC running Windows. In that case, you should replace the `127.0.0.1` with the actual IP address of Ubuntu server (the one you use for PuTTY).

Answer (score -1):

I am also developing in a virtual machine.

Use `ifconfig` to figure out the IP address that has been assigned to your virtual machine.

Then start the server with:

```
python manage.py runserver <IP>:8000
```

Of course you could also use a different port instead of `8000`. Then use that address and port in your host browser to access your server.

Note: At least in my VM, the virtual machine gets a new address from time to time, so check that in case you have trouble starting your server with the same command.

If this does not help, check your hosts file as mentioned in one of the comments.